# MySQL: JOIN (A, B) with SUM B, but B is not exist rows in some case

Tags: mysql, join

> Hello everyone, I'm a stackoverflow novice.
>
> If I have any wrong about asking this question, hope to redress me.
>   :)

I want to make a asking question system, and I have two Tables in MySQL.

1. Table 'question' : It stores the question info.
2. Table 'question_communication' : It stores the replies of question between manager and user.

---

Here is the detail Table.

```
question (Table)
    - question_id(INT)
    - uid(INT)
    - category(CHAR)
    - description(CHAR)
    - submit_time(DATETIME)
```

And

```
question_communication (Table)
    - question_reply_id(INT)
    - question_id(INT)
    - uid(ID)
    - reply(CHAR)
    - time(DATETIME)
    - seen(TINYINT)           --- Other side has seen the message or not.(0 is not seen, 1 is seen)
```

---

I want the query result is include :

`question_id, uid, category, description, submit_time, seen(=1), seen(=0)`

Then I try to write to code below,

```
SELECT T1.question_id, T1.uid, T1.category, T1.description, DATE_FORMAT(T1.submit_time, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i') submit_time, SUM(T2.seen = 1) seen, SUM(T2.seen = 0) notseen
  FROM question T1, question_communication T2
  WHERE T1.question_id = T2.question_id
    AND T2.uid != (Here is attribute.)
  ORDER BY submit_time DESC
```

But `WHERE T1.question_id = T2.question_id` this line may not work in one case.

When `T1 (question)` has a question,

and it doesn't have any reply in `T2 (question_communication)`.

So `T1.question_id = T2.question_id` will cause SQL `JOIN` out of my expectation.

---

My problem summary:

1. How to query successfully the result like:

`question_id, uid, category, description, submit_time, seen(=1), seen(=0)`

2. If there is question in T1, but no reply in T2. `seen(=1)` and `seen(=0)` must be `zero`.

---

Thanks everyone :)

---

Answer from @Gordon Linoff, and I add the COALESCE() :

```
SELECT T1.question_id, T1.uid, T1.category, T1.description,
       DATE_FORMAT(T1.submit_time, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i') as submit_time,
       COALESCE(SUM(T2.seen = 1), 0) as seen, COALESCE(SUM(T2.seen = 0), 0) as notseen
FROM question T1 LEFT JOIN
     question_communication T2
     ON T1.question_id = T2.question_id 
GROUP BY T1.question_id, T1.uid, T1.category, T1.description,
         DATE_FORMAT(T1.submit_time, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i') 
ORDER BY submit_time DESC;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just need a `left join`.  In fact, you should always use explicit `join` syntax.  Your query also needs a `group by`.  So, the query looks something like:

```
SELECT T1.question_id, T1.uid, T1.category, T1.description,
       DATE_FORMAT(T1.submit_time, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i') as submit_time,
       SUM(T2.seen = 1) as seen, SUM(T2.seen = 0) as notseen
FROM question T1 LEFT JOIN
     question_communication T2
     ON T1.question_id = T2.question_id 
GROUP BY T1.question_id, T1.uid, T1.category, T1.description,
         DATE_FORMAT(T1.submit_time, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i') 
ORDER BY submit_time DESC;
```

I don't know what `T2.uid != (Here is attribute.)` is supposed to do.  If you have a filtering condition on `T2`, then put it in the `ON` clause.

Comment: yes, 'T2.uid != xxx' this line is a filtering condition. I'm sorry about my English :")

Comment: `COALESCE(SUM(T2.seen = 1), 0) as seen, COALESCE(SUM(T2.seen = 0), 0) as notseen`, add the COALESCE() will complete it :D